# Onnx to tensorrt arcface model conversion error on jetson nano(segmentation fault core dumped)

Tags: deep-learning, segmentation-fault, tensorrt, onnx, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am converting arcface model of onnx version to tensorrt. I am following the official nvidia document for the process. But,I am getting an error of segmentation fault core dumped. Please provide your best possible suggestions. I am running it on jetson nano.

Comment: Hey there, are you using the onnx-tensorrt tool? https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt Please provide more steps to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to convert your model to tensorrt on a more capable machine. Then you can try to run it on jetson nano. The conversion operation can be more demanding than the inference sometimes. I have also encountered a similar issue with SSD_mobilenet_v2 conversion. I tried to convert in on jetson but it failed so I made the conversion on my laptop which has a 1050m.